# If we are given a series from n to infinity and know it is non-negative and convergent, is it also decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I was given a $\ \sum_{n}^{\infty} a_{n}$ and know that it is non-negative and convergent. I was curious since we know its convergent and by the necessary/sufficient condition its limit as n goes to infinity is 0, is the sequence {${a_{n}}$} decreasing? More explicitly is it true that ${a_{n}}$ > ${a_{n+1}}$? I can only think of the sequence 1 + 1 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.25 + 0.25 ... as a counterexample but I'm not sure if its a good one. Thank you

Comment: That is a perfectly good counterexample to $a_n>a_{n+1}$.  If you want a counterexample to the even weaker condition that $a_n\geq a_{n+1}$ consider $1+0+0.5+0+0.25+0+0.125+0+\dots$

Comment: Given any nonnegative sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, what can you say about $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac12(1+(-1)^n) a_n$?

Comment: $a_n=\frac1  {n^{2}}$ for $n$ even,  $a_n=0$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: try $0.9+1.1+0.4+0.6+0.249+0.251+...$